# Determine the value of k in the following system of equations given that it has infinite solutions.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

For this question:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    x & -2y & 3z = -1 \\
    2x & -4y & 6z = -2 \\
    -x & 2y & kz = 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I ended up with this for the bottom two rows using the augmented matrix approach:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&(k+3)&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

I got k = -3 but the answer is supposed to be that k has infinite solutions...

Whereas for this question I got k = -1 which is correct:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    x & -y & z = 3 \\
    2x & 3y & kz = 2 \\
    4x & 11y & -5z = 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

How are these two questions different? Why is k infinite solutions in the first question and not the second? I used the augmented matrix approach to work this out so please use that method to explain to me how! Thanks.

Comment: `I used the augmented matrix approach to work this out` Then please post your work so that we can see where your $k=-3$ came from. `How are these two questions different?` Look at the top two equations in the first question more closely. P.S. Btw you post is missing a lot of "$+$" signs.

Comment: Sorry, I find it hard to write using this MathJax thing! :/

Comment: I added some working out, is that enough?

Comment: The top two equations are identical (they only differ by a factor of $2$) so you have a system of two equations with three unknowns, unlike in the second case. The augmented matrix written this way only tells you that $(k+3)z=0$, but that still leaves infinitely many solutions for $z=0$ regardless of $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm still just a bit confused. For the second question augmented matrix I got (3k + 3)z = 0, does that not leave infinitely many solutions for z = 0 regardless of k? Why do two identical equations result in infinite solutions for k?

Comment: In the first case, $z=0$ reduces the system to one single equation and $x=2y-1, z=0$ is a solution for $\forall y$ regardless of $k$. This does not happen in the second case. You could restate this in terms of matrix ranks and/or augmented matrices, I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much, I see!